# Proxmox LXC storage share, permission problems

Tags: permissions, bind-mount, proxmox, uid

I'm totally new in these enviroments but I'm trying to learn.
I installed proxmox on a single SSD, then attached one HDD(/dev/sdb) to the system for media storage. The basic idea was to create one container for Plex app and one for rtorrent app. I would like to share the same space(disk) between these containers.

On the host I mounted /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/mediastorage, and created a user called "mediastorage"(110:117) and add access to this space. 
Both of the containers I added this(/mnt/mediastorage) to /mediastorage mount point.Like this:

```
mp0: /mnt/mediastorage/,mp=/mediastorage
```

After that,I tried to grant access for these files for plex(107:115) user in the "plex" container:

```
lxc.idmap: u 0 100000 107
lxc.idmap: u 107 110 1
lxc.idmap: u 108 100125 64410
lxc.idmap: g 0 100000 115
lxc.idmap: g 115 117 1
lxc.idmap: g 116 100136 64399
```

On the host I did this:

```
root@proxmox:~# cat /etc/subuid
root:100000:65536
root:110:1
root@proxmox:~# cat /etc/subgid
root:100000:65536
root:117:1
```

Later, I created the other container, where created a user called rtorrent(107:115) and did the same config like the "plex" container.

There was a moment where everything seemd fine but after a reboot(host) incomprehensive things happened like this: [Previous thread where it started](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563942/debian-change-owner-of-nobodynogroup)

Noticed that at the "plex" container, appeared a new entry in the /etc/passwd file:

```
mediastorage:x:108:116:...etc
```

/etc/group:

```
mediastorage:x:116:
```

-these were not there earlier and the container was in shutdown state.

```
root@plex:/# ls -al /home
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Jan 23 20:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root    4096 Jan 24 22:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup 4096 Jan 23 20:57 mediastorage
```

Can somebody explain it what happened here please?
How can I achieve my main idea?(share storage between the containers)
Is it possible in this way?

**EDIT1:**
Reinstalled the container, first mounted the /mediastorage than installed plex than add uid mapping to the container's config.(Somewhere I read that maxbe it will work).Now the storage works but the plex service can't start because of permission issues.
From the host -- lxc container's disk mounted as /mnt/lxc102:

```
/mnt/lxc102/etc/passwd:
plex:x:107:115::/var/lib/plexmediaserver:/bin/bash
/mnt/lxc102/etc/group:
plex:x:115:
ls -al /mnt/lxc102:
drwxr-xr-x  2 100000 100000  4096 Jan 25 23:22 mediastorage
ls -al /mnt/lxc102/var/lib:
drwxr-xr-x  3 100107 100115 4096 Jan 25 23:25 plexmediaserver
```

On the container, the plexmediaserver directory listed as nobody:nogroup again.

Comment: Your settings are too complex for me. But for all these files, you should list them from the host, using `ls -n` rather than from the container: you will then get the real host uid, rather than always get the "overflow uid/gid" 65534:65534. Then you might do some (difficult) calculations to get an idea. Obviously the hosts uids don't map (anymore?) into the container uids.

Comment: Somewhere I read, that I should mount the partition first then create the user.Now the /mediastorage looks like this: drwxr-xr-x  2 100000 100000  4096 Jan 25 23:22 mediastorage (and mounted as plex user so it has acces for it) but one of the "plex" users library: drwxr-xr-x  3 100107 100115 4096 Jan 25 23:25 plexmediaserver from the host.

Comment: Those 100107:100115 should probably be 110:117 . Are you sure the mappings are actually set as you intend on the running containers? from the host find a process running in a container (run a sleep command from it if it's too difficult) and check with cat /proc/PID/uid_map etc . You must understand how the mappings work so you can do many tests and experiments. There's no way to solve it here on UL because there are too many unknowns

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
Output of the sleep: (cat /proc/9990/uid_map)
         0     100000        107  ...
       107        110          1     ...
       108     100108      64530   ...
So this is totally wrong if i understand well.

Comment: The container looks ok. That means something else (an other container?) had wrong settings, or there's a bug. Of course if there's a bug there's nothing much to do, except try to pin point it.

Comment: No other containers are running since reinstalled the container so it should be a bug. I will try to avoid it some ways. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I solved it by adding `unprivileged: 0` in the `/etc/pve/lxc/???.conf` file (where ??? is the ID of your lxc container).

Comment: This fixed the issue for me! Thanks!

Comment: While i understand that this works, it's a huge security issue... your container runs as root..